# No JsonAdapter for Generic Type (inside generic function)

Tags: kotlin, moshi

I am facing an error `No JsonAdapter for R` when parsing JSON to data class inside a generic function, I researched and tried many ways but it is still not working. 
The problem is that `generic function` doesn't know what is actually the type of generic parameter `R` so I can't manually assign the type of R when parsing.

How can I resolve this problem? :(

```
fun <T, R> sendRequest(msg: Deribit.Request.Message<T>): Deribit.Response.Result<R> {
    ...
        val type = object : TypeToken<Deribit.Response.Result<R>>() {}.type

        return moshi.adapter<Deribit.Response.Result<R>>(
            type
        ).fromJson(jsonElement.toString())
    ...
}
```

I also use `reified` function that return `ParameterizedTypeReference` but it still not working

```
private inline fun <reified T: Any> typeRef(): ParameterizedTypeReference<T> = object: ParameterizedTypeReference<T>(){}
...
// USAGE
val data = moshi.adapter<Deribit.Response.Result<R>>(
            typeRef<Deribit.Response.Result<R>>().type
        ).fromJson(jsonElement.toString())
```

Thank you and best regards!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making it

```
inline fun <reified T, reified R> sendRequest...
```

should work. Alternately, pass the type you need or enough to construct it as an argument. E.g.

```
fun <T, R> sendRequest(msg: Deribit.Request.Message<T>, clazzR: Class<R>): Deribit.Response.Result<R> {
    // Type object for Result<R>
    val type = Types.newParameterizedType(Deribit.Response.Result::class.java, clazzR)
    ...
}
```